# Unity Getting A Gun To Follow A Camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using this to get my gun moving with the camera but it doesn't rotate with the camera for some reason.

```
//Updating Position
transform.position = cameraToFollow.transform.position + (Quaternion.Euler(0, targetYRotation, 0) * new Vector3(holdSide, holdHeight, 1));

targetXRotation = Mathf.SmoothDamp( targetXRotation, cameraToFollow.transform.rotation.x, ref targetXRotationV, rotateSpeed);
targetYRotation = Mathf.SmoothDamp( targetYRotation, cameraToFollow.transform.rotation.y, ref targetYRotationV, rotateSpeed);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (targetXRotation, targetYRotation, 0);

transform.parent = cameraToFollow.transform;
```

Comment: I assume you're having problems with the Unity3D game engine, not the Unity application block for .NET.

Comment: Yes the Unity3D Game Engine.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to be an answer which provides a solution to your code, but more or less a design hint. I've created quite a few first-person games, with my current project being a large-scale FPS called `desert storm`. Instead of writing a script to attach the gun to the camera, simply set the gun as a child of the camera in the inspector.

If you're changing between first and third person like I do, you'd simply change the parent of the transform whenever you go to 3rd person.